# Question about uniqueness of a specific Hahn-Banach extension

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $X = C([0,1])$, and $L = Span(t)$. Defining the functional $f(x):= \lambda$ when $x \in L$ is $\lambda t$.

Clearly, $||f||_{L^*} = 1$.

From Hahn-Banach, it can be extended to $F \in X^*$, with $||F||_{X^*} = 1$.

The functional $\phi$ defined by $\phi(z) = z(1)$ works as a norm-preserving extension.

My question is, is this extension unique, or is there another one?
In case it is unique, how would one go on about proving it?

EDIT:
By $t$ I mean the identity in $[0,1]$

Comment: I guess $t$ is a certain element of $C[0,1]$?  Perhaps specify which one it is.

Comment: In general, if $X$ is a normed linear space, $L = \operatorname{span} t \subseteq X$, and $f : L \to \Bbb{R} : \lambda t \to \lambda$, then $\|f\|_{L^*} = \|t\|_X$ (not necessarily $1$). Also, $f$ will have a unique extension to $X$ if and only if the norm $\|\cdot\|_X$ is Gateaux differentiable at $t$. Certainly, this will not be true for all $t$ (under the $\infty$-norm?): if there exist two points at which $t(x) = 1$, then the evaluation functionals at those two points will be distinct extensions of $f$. Are there points at which $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is Gateaux smooth? I honestly don't know.

Comment: I suspect that $t$ refers to the function $t \mapsto t$ on $[0,1]$

Comment: The extension is unique as the function $t\mapsto t$ attains its maximum at the unique point $1$ and $\varphi(t)=1=\|t\|_\infty.$ The extension is the point evaluation at $1.$

Comment: @daw The OP functional satisfies $\varphi(t)=\|t\|_\infty$ while for $C[0,2]$ there holds $\varphi(t)={1\over 2}\|t\|_\infty.$ That's why the extension on the new space is not unique, unlike for $C[0,1].$